# How to use DTD and XSL in the same XML

Tags: xml, xslt, dtd

I am trying to show my XML by using XSL, and at the same time to make my XML well-formed I used DTD. The problem is that whenever I put the DTD link on the XML the web-page goes blank. And if I delete the DTD link everything works fine. How do I combine both DTD and XML?

The XML code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="erakutsi.xsl"?>
 <!DOCTYPE trantzakzioak SYSTEM "xml_eskema.xsd">

 <trantzakzioak>
    <trantzakzioa erabiltzailea="bs123@ikasle.ehu.eus" mota="DiruS">                        
            <kontzeptua>Lanean irabazitakoa</kontzeptua>     
            <kantitatea>4000.0</kantitatea>
    </trantzakzioa>
</trantzakzioak>
```

The DTD code:

```
 <!ELEMENT trantzakzioak (trantzakzioa)*>
 <!ATTLIST trantzakzioak>
 <!ELEMENT trantzakzioa (kontzeptua,kantitatea)>
 <!ATTLIST trantzakzioa erabiltzailea #PCDATA #REQUIRED>
 <!ATTLIST trantzakzioa mota #PCDATA #REQUIRED>
 <!ELEMENT kontzeptua (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT kantitatea (#PCDATA)>
```

The XSL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<HTML>
    <BODY>
        <h2>Galderak</h2>
        <TABLE border="1">
            <TR>
                <TH>Testua</TH>

            </TR>
            <xsl:for-each select="/trantzakzioak/trantzakzioa" >
                <TR>
                    <TD><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="red" FACE="Verdana">
                        <xsl:value-of select="kontzeptua"/> <BR/>
                        </FONT>
                    </TD>
                </TR>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </TABLE>
    </BODY>
</HTML></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is that the complete DTD? Are you sure it does not additionally declare an `xmlns="..."` attribute on the root element or some other elements?

Comment: Your DTD is invalid. It can not contain `#PCDATA` type in `ATTLLIST`. I guess it needs to be changed to `CDATA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally syntax  should be as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE [Top-level element] [Publicity] "[Registration]//[Organization]//[Type] [Name]//[Language]" "[URL]">
```

Parameters:

Top-level element - indicates the top-level element in the document, for HTML this is the  tag.

Publicity - an object is public (value PUBLIC) or system resource (value SYSTEM), for example, such as a local file. For HTML / XHTML, the value PUBLIC is specified.

Registration - reports that the developer of DTD is registered with the International Organization for Standardization (ISO). It takes one of two values: plus (+) - the developer is registered in ISO and - (minus) - the developer is not registered. For W3C, the value is set to "-".

Organization - the unique name of the organization that developed the DTD. Officially, HTML / XHTML publishes the W3C, this name and is written in .

Type - the type of the document described. For HTML / XHTML, the value is specified by the DTD.

Name - unique name of the document to describe the DTD.

Language - in which the text is written to describe the object. Contains two letters, written in uppercase. The HTML (XHTML) document specifies the English language (EN).

URL - of the document with the DTD.

So in your case, if xml_eskema.dtd as below:

```
<!ELEMENT trantzakzioak (trantzakzioa)*>
 <!ATTLIST trantzakzioak>
 <!ELEMENT trantzakzioa (kontzeptua,kantitatea)>
 <!ATTLIST trantzakzioa erabiltzailea CDATA #REQUIRED>
 <!ATTLIST trantzakzioa mota CDATA #REQUIRED>
 <!ELEMENT kontzeptua (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT kantitatea (#PCDATA)>
```

Then your XML DOCTYPE declaration should be as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="erakutsi.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE trantzakzioak PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML//EN' 'xml_eskema.dtd'>

 <trantzakzioak>
    <trantzakzioa erabiltzailea="bs123@ikasle.ehu.eus" mota="DiruS">                        
            <kontzeptua>Lanean irabazitakoa</kontzeptua>     
            <kantitatea>4000.0</kantitatea>
    </trantzakzioa>
</trantzakzioak>
```

As a result you will see it as below:

[image]